# How many unique subsets of size 3 can there be from a 5 element set?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm solving a problem that uses Combinations and it's driving me crazy. The question requires the number of unique subsets (order does not matter) from 5 elements. I believe the answer should just be C(5, 3) correct?

$\frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!}$ that is.

However, as I manually list out all these sets. I am only getting 9, as my answer, not 10.... C(5, 3) = 10.

$(A, B, C, D, E)\\
(A, B, C)\\
(A, B, D)\\
(A, B, E)\\
(A, C, D)\\
(A, C, E)\\
(A, D, E)\\
(B, C, D)\\
(B, D, E)\\
(C, D, E)\\
$

The question requires that there cannot be any duplicate element sets, so the order does not matter. Hence the set (A, B, C) = (B, A, C).
Is this not a combination or am I just missing one of the subsets? Thanks.

Comment: missing $(B,C,E)$...

Comment: Man, I'm an idiot and you're a live saver. So it was a combination afterall correct?

Comment: It was correct, well done for that.

Comment: Lol literally same thing happened to me, but I knew it was a combination so I googled it to find what the hell I've been missing and it was (B,D,E) for me

Comment: @ch0wner happens to the best of us haha